# How to find the schema for a sobject

Tags: rest-api, sobject, schema

I am trying to build an API which under the hood will perform CRUD operations against the Salesforce API. I'm using the [node-salesforce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-salesforce) library for communication with Salesforce.

An example of creating a new `Contact` record:

```
  let newContact: SalesforceContact = {
    firstName: contact.firstName,
    lastName: contact.lastName,
    email: contact.email,
  }

  let response: any
  try {
    response = await sf.sobject('Contact').create(newContact)
  } catch (err) {...}
```

Which is fine, but when I try to do the same for `Lead`:

```
  let newLead: SalesforceLead = {
    name: lead.name,
    email: lead.email,
  }

  let response: any
  try {
    response = await sf.sobject('Lead').create(newLead)
  } catch (err) {...}
```

I get an error:

```
"INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE: Unable to create/update fields: Name. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set."
```

Or when I try to pass `{name, email}` to the `Account` sobject, I get the same error for `email`. Once I remove it - I can create accounts.

So, apparently some of the fields in the object that I pass are wrong or non-existent. I am wondering if there is a place to find reference or documentation about the Salesforce API's schema.

I have tried searching stuff, but I mostly find examples of certain queries. And I need to have a full reference of the fields, so I have my options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lead's `Name` is a compound field and you cannot directly write values in `Name` field. Instead you will need to use the `FirstName`, `LastName` (same as you have with Contact).

The [SOAP API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) lists down the standard fields that is available for a particular SObject in Salesforce. You can additionally use the [Object Management Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_click_find_objectmgmt_parent.htm&type=5) for a particular SObject or [Schema Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=schema_builder.htm&type=5) to view these details within your Salesforce Org.

Comment: The SOAP API docs was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can access the the Salesforce ORG agains which you are performing operations and can check under the [Schema builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=schema_builder.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%2F&type=5), where you will see something like this:
[image],

additionally, you can check the [Object Reference for Salesforce and Lightning Platform](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [Schema Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/data_modeling/schema_builder) in Setup for available fields in your org (including custom fields), the [Field Reference Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/) for standard objects and fields, and other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the objects directly in SFDC, perhaps this Force.com REST API sObject Resources should help you out:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Lead

Answer (score 0):

The Object Manager and Schema Builder won't help you with many standard objects like [FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm). Instead use the `sfdx` command line:

```
# Lists all objects
sfdx force:schema:sobject:list

# See the schema
sfdx force:schema:sobject:describe -s FeedItem
```

For more info run `sfdx sfdx force:schema:sobject --help` or read the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_schema.htm).